# Movie or TV episode, 80s/90s, about kids contacting evil alien through their computer

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

My memories are incredibly vague, but here goes…

I saw this on TV in Finland in the early 1990s, when I was young. I can't remember whether it was a film or a TV episode. I think they spoke English.

There was a group of kids, who had a desktop computer, and somehow had contacted some alien or monster through it. I have a vague feeling that the creature was in space at this point, but might not have been. The alien spoke to them aloud through the computer, which it might have taken over. My clearest memory is that the CRT monitor of the computer turned like a head to look at one of them, and said something like "You are [that character's name]". It might have told them something about its intentions, but in any case the kids realized that the thing was dangerous, but it was too late and they had attracted its attention or summoned it somehow.

Later, the alien/monster had appeared. My only memory is of a humanoid monster, not very well visible in the dark, maybe in some woods, possibly with cheesy backlighting and smoke machine.

Comment: Interesting as this resonates with things that became quite common on the Internet. It also reminds me of the cartoon captioned: On the Internet no one knows you are a dog.

Comment: There’s a Buffy episode where a demon is trapped in a book, the book is scanned into a computer so the demon is now trapped in the computer. It talks to kids at the school via the computers in the lab and eventually manipulates them into helping him take form in the real world. Could it be that?

Comment: Buffy didn't air in Finland until 1999, when I was already 15 years old. This must have been earlier, more like 1990–1995.